# Matrix form for Weighted Least Squares

Tags: statistics, regression

If we have the following weighted least-squares regression, with

$\hat{\beta} = (X'WX)^{-1}X'WY$

How can we express the squared errors, MSE and the fitted values in matrix form?

These are the OLS equivalent:

$Squared Error_i = (\hat{y}_i - y_i )^2$

$Mean Squared Error(MSE) = \Sigma(\hat{y}_i - y_i)^2/(N-p)$

$Fitted Value_i = \hat{y}_i=  \hat{\beta} * x_i$

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

One approach is to consider transformed variables. If you define e.g. 
$$
X^*=W^{1/2}X\\
Y^*=W^{1/2}Y
$$
and apply this transformation, you can write your estimator as
$$
\hat{\beta}=(X'WX)^{-1}X'WY=({X^*}'X^*)^{-1}{X^*}'Y^*
$$
which is regular OLS, but it is applied to a transformed regression. Can you see what such a transformation means in terms of the scalar quantities you are looking for?

Comment: Not really actually, not in terms of $\hat {\beta}$

Comment: In other words, $\hat{Y^*} = X(X'WX)^{-1}X'WY$ or would it be $\hat{Y^*} = W^{1/2}X(X'WX)^{-1}X'WY$ ???

Comment: The $\hat\beta$ is still exactly the same, so $\hat Y=X\hat\beta=X(X'WX)^{-1}X'WY$. Weighted least squares like you're doing is equivalent to OLS of $Y^*=X^*\beta+e$, where $V(e)=\sigma^2 I$. Initially, you have $Y=X\beta+u$, where $V(u)=W^{-1}$. If you premultiply by $W^{1/2}$, you get $W^{1/2}Y=W^{1/2}X\beta+W^{1/2}u$ which we for simplicity can call $Y^*=X^*\beta+e$. So we transform the regression to get rid of the heteroskedasticity, and then what remains is a nice model in the sense that we can just apply OLS.